# Average of filtered values by criteria

Tags: sql, subquery, average

During executing the query below the following message comes:

> Msg 130, Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

```
SELECT DATEADD(n,-10,[TimeStampLocalSystem]) as Date,
AVG(CASE WHEN [Minute10Average]>0 THEN [Minute10Average] END) AS Average,
AVG(CASE WHEN ABS(1-Minute10Average/AVG(CASE WHEN [Minute10Average]>0 THEN [Minute10Average] END))<0.5 THEN Minute10Average END) AS Average_corr
FROM [XXX]
INNER JOIN [XXX]
ON [XXX].Systemnumber=[YYY].SystemNumber
WHERE [TimeStampLocalSystem] BETWEEN '2022-09-16 17:10:00' AND '2022-09-16 18:20:00' 
AND [DataPointID] IN (XXX)
AND RIGHT(FORMAT([TimeStampLocalSystem],'DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss'),4) = '0:00'
GROUP BY [TimeStampLocalSystem]
```

The problem is in the line:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN ABS(1-Minute10Average/AVG(CASE WHEN [Minute10Average]>0 THEN [Minute10Average] END))<0.5 THEN Minute10Average END) AS Average_corr
```

Could you help me to define what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use Having and the aggregate filter.

```
select name, sum(field) from table group by name having sum(field)>1
```